# How to add path in following shopware structure

Tags: templates, smarty, shopware

I am new to Shopware and would like to add a new path (e.g. /brands) to the shopware site. Since it's pretty split up, I don't know where to start.

The tutorial from this link
https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-quick-start/
wasn't that helpful, since the smarty template files aren't located in

```
/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Shopware
```

but in

```
/templates/ShopnameXY/
```

(I am designing the new shop tpls in there, the old ones are in another dir named /templates/ShopnameXYold)

I know that I somehow have to add a directory in the Shopware directory with a Bootstrap.php file, but even looking at existing Bootstrap.php files, I can't find any hint of other pathes being created (e.g. /bottom/legal)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand your question.

> would like to add a new path (e.g. /brands) to the shopware site.

In case you want to add new path with your own page you should create new controller:

```
public function install() {
    $this->registerController('Frontend', 'Example');
}
```

Controller should be placed to `OurPluginRoot/Controllers/Frontend/Example.php`

```
class Shopware_Controllers_Frontend_Example extends Enlight_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->assign('variable', 'value');
    }
}
```

And then we add template for index action our new controller to `OurPluginRoot/View/example/index.tpl`

```
{extends file='frontend/index/index.tpl'}
{block name="frontend_index_content"}
    <div class="container">
        My own controller view
    </div>
{/block}
```

Set path to existed controllers you can via backend.

In case you need to extend existed template you need to write pretty easy plugin for this.

```
class Shopware_Plugins_Frontend_ExtendQuickCart_Bootstrap extends Shopware_Components_Plugin_Bootstrap {
/**
 * Returns the version of plugin as string.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getVersion() {
    return '0.0.1';
}

/**
 * Returns the plugin name for backend
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLabel() {
    return 'Extend Quick Cart View';
}

/**
 * Standard plugin install method to register all required components.
 * @return array
 */
public function install() {
        $this->subscribeEvent();
}    

/**
 * @return Shopware_Plugins_Frontend_ExtendQuickCart_Bootstrap
 */
private function subscribeEvents(){
    //Frontend_Checkout -> Frontend/Backend, Checkout mean controller checkout
    $this->subscribeEvent(
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatch_Frontend_Checkout', 'onPostDispatchCheckout'
    );

    return $this;
}
/**
 * @param Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs $arguments
 */
public function onPostDispatchCheckout(Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs $arguments){
    /**@var $controller Shopware_Controllers_Frontend_Checkout */
    $controller = $arguments->getSubject();
    $request  = $controller->Request();
    $response = $controller->Response();
    $action = $request->getActionName();
    $view = $controller->View();

    // Extend only ajaxCart Action, all other actions - don't do anything
    if (  $action !== 'ajaxCart' || !$request->isDispatched()
        || $response->isException() || !$view->hasTemplate()
    ) {
        return;
    }
        $view->addTemplateDir($this->Path() . 'Views/');
  }
}
```

Then create template `OurPluginRoot/View/checkout/ajax_cart.tpl`

```
{extends file='parent:frontend/checkout/ajax_cart.tpl'}
{block name='frontend_checkout_ajax_cart_prices_container_inner'}
    <div class="prices--articles">
        <span class="prices--articles-text">{s name="AjaxCartTotalAmount"}{/s}</span>
        <span class="prices--articles-amount">{$sBasket.Amount|currency}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="prices--articles">
        <span class="prices--articles-text">{s name="AjaxSomething"}Something{/s}</span>
        <span class="prices--articles-amount">{$sBasket.Amount}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="prices--articles">
        <span class="prices--articles-text">{s name="AjaxSomething1"}Something ssecond{/s}</span>
        <span class="prices--articles-amount">@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</span>
    </div>
{/block}
```

[There](http://shopwarrior.net/sample/ExtendAdvanced.zip) you can find archive with test plugin which you can study, hope this will be useful for you.